# Solvent for Norland Optical Adhesive

Tags: polymers, solvents

I'd like to know if there is any solvent that dissolves [Norland Optical Adhesive 65](https://www.norlandprod.com/adhesives/noa%2065.html) (and [Rhodamine 6G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodamine_6G)), but does not dissolve [PMMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly(methyl_methacrylate)) that is used in e-beam lithography.

I've tried acetone, methanol, chloroform, *n*-hexane and toluene; none worked.

Comment: Can you provide the solvents that do dissolve your adhesive and the PMMA together?

Comment: In Acetone,Methanol,Chloroform, and Toluene both are soluble. Whereas in n-Hexane both are insoluble

Comment: Is the adhesive some sort of thiocarbamate do you know? Have you tried ester solvents?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't try esters because, both PMMA and NOA65 are soluble even in toluene of polarity 2.4. I need something that has polarity greater than 0.2 (as that of cyclohexane) and less than 2.4 (that of toluene)

Comment: Are you using Hansen solubility parameters?